# Variables in the regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

Would it be correct if the outcome variable is at the household level, to use variables at both household and household member level as regression explanatory variables?

E.g. if the outcome variable is whether household has water supply, and predictors are household's geographic region, type of floor; member's age, sex, and education.

Comment: Exactly how are your representing these data when there is more than one member per household?  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "use"?  That must depend on what kind of model you have and what kind of analysis you are attempting.

Comment: @whuber I am analyzing whether household owns, has access to a computer or none. Therefore, I am using multinomial model to assess the impact of various household's and individual's socio-economic factors on the probability of adopting a computer by a household. Every record in the dataset represents household members' responds. Sample is weighted, meaning some records represents more households than other in the population.  The sample followed a two-stage, replicated and rotable design in which enumeration areas (EAs) are primary sampling units from which households (secondary sampling unit)

Answer (score 0):

In short: yes. That is, if I understand the question right. It is somewhat vague and I am not sure about the English.

If I am understanding it right though, this is not a regression problem but a classification problem.

This can be moved up as a comment if OP thinks so.

Comment: Dependent variable is binary, and explanatory variables are related to household and household members socio-economic characteristics - I hope it's a little bit clearer. Additionaly, would you recommend using weights in the regression analysis? Every record in the sample has weight which is the number of household represented in the population. If I am not mistaken, these are post-stratification weights. However, I am confused whether to use iz in regression analysis? I am using Stata and I was thinking to use the pweight option to estimate multinomial logit model.